# Multi-threading in a node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Does it possible to create multiple threads in a nodejs. I am not asking by using Cluster or
fork or exec way. Its actually creating child process instead of thread. I want actual implementation of separate thread in node.js.

Comment: There is only one thread in node.js, you can use spawn to start more instance of node.js, but child_process will be much more effective. What are you trying to multi thread?

Comment: What are you trying to do? It's likely you don't actually need threads.

Comment: But on only one thread my application is responding late as it is executing series of jobs in parallel. So I want to execute important jobs in a separate thread so it will responds fast to that jobs.

Comment: @Sanket: That s what child process are for!

Comment: Ya I know that but if parent and child are referring to same db which I am using at a time and at a time  of writing data to db these process through an error message that's why I am looking for threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NodeJS doesn't currently support multiple threads. There's been talk about (and even work on) providing thread support, but it hasn't happened (yet?). There doesn't seem to be much impetus in that regard.

A search for "NodeJS multiple threads" will find things like [JXcore](http://jxcore.com/home/), though, which claims 100% NodeJS compatibility (it's a fork with "added features"). YMMV.

Comment: Ok thanks but is there any way by which we can apply priority to queued jobs in a event loop of nodejs.

Comment: @Sanket: That would be a completely separate question. I'd post it as one.

Answer (score 0):

As T.J. Crowder mention, you can use [JXcore](https://github.com/jxcore/jxcore) for this. It is an open source project now.

The simplest way to run an app multi-threaded would be:

```
console.log("Hello thread", process.threadId);
```

and you run it this way:

```
$ jx mt:3 hello.js
```

It runs 3 threads/instances inside of one process.

There are also other ways with Jxcore, to use [tasks](https://github.com/jxcore/jxcore/blob/master/doc/api/jxcore-tasks.markdown) in threads.